# Combining partition types lvm

Tags: linux, lvm, diskmanagement, gpt

I have an older disk setup that was made with msdos parition types and it appears that they kept growing the same disk in order to grow the lvm however it ran into an issue where it got to 2TB and couldn't grow anymore. The client wanted to attach an additional 3TB disk to the lvm however you can only do 2TB with msdos parition type so I instead made it GPT (also trying to keep future growth in mind since historically they seem to grow the disks instead of attaching additional). It joined the lvm ok and the fsck and everything went fine. The OS is not booting off this disk and reboots went ok.

Does anyone see any potential issues with this setup? Any roadblocks to future growth? e.g. combining msdos/GPT partitions in the same lvm.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a partition as an LVM PV then it doesn't matter whether the disk was partitioned as MSDOS or GPT. LVM does not operate at this level; it doesn't care at all where the block device came from.